# echo variable with content from command substitution

Tags: shell, quoting, echo, command-substitution

I wrote a very basic script of command substitution which is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(ls *.fastq);
echo $files
```

The directory contains bunch of .fastq file and I just want to use echo command to output them

The above sript outputs fastq files with a space between each fastq filename.

When I use it in this way

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(ls *.fastq);
echo "$files"
```

it prints the results on new lines.

Why is it so? Is it something to do with command substitution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes. This prevents reinterpretation of all special characters within the quoted string -- except `$`, `` ` `` (backquote), and `\` (escape). Keeping `$` as a special character within double quotes permits referencing a quoted variable ("$variable"), that is, replacing the variable with its value.

Use double quotes to prevent word splitting. An argument enclosed in double quotes presents itself as a single word, even if it contains whitespace separators.

e.g.

```
variable1="a variable containing five words"
COMMAND This is $variable1    # Executes COMMAND with 7 arguments:
# "This" "is" "a" "variable" "containing" "five" "words"

COMMAND "This is $variable1"  # Executes COMMAND with 1 argument:
# "This is a variable containing five words"
```

**Enclosing the arguments to an echo statement in double quotes is necessary only when word splitting or preservation of whitespace is an issue.**

For more info and examples go [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Answer (score 6):

You have newlines because `ls` puts them on separate lines. The newlines disappear without the quotes because the shell (bash) passes each unquoted space separated text to the command as a separate argument.

Note: The command substitution is done by the shell, **not by `ls`**, so you do not need `ls`.

Therefore you can do

```
#!/bin/bash
echo *.fastq
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
files="*.fastq"
echo "$files"
```

Comment: running ls *.fastq on the terminal outputs on the same line separated by spaces, how is ls putting them on separate lines then?

Comment: I can not find the docs, but `ls` will output same as `ls -x` when to a tty, and like `ls -1` when not. Therefore use `ls -x` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to a variable without quotes around it (e.g. `echo $files`), the shell splits the value apart on whitespace and passes each term as a separate command-line option.  Newlines are treated the same as any other whitespace.  The `echo` program doesn't see the newline characters at all; it just gets an array of strings, each of which is a single filename.

When you refer to a variable in quotes (e.g. `echo "$files"`), the shell doesn't do any whitespace splitting; instead, it passes the entire value, unmodified, as a *single* argument.  The `echo` program receives one long string that includes the newline characters.

Variables aside, this is the same behavior you get with quotes around literal values.  If you write `echo foo     bar`, the spaces are stripped out by the shell and `echo` just gets the strings `foo` and `bar`, and it'll print those strings with a single space between them, since that's how it's coded to combine multiple arguments.  If you write `echo "foo     bar"`, `echo` gets the single string `foo     bar` and will print it as-is.