# How to print multiline output of script into file with newline

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following script:

`/usr/bin/daily-execution`

```
#!/bin/bash
log_folder=/var/log/hans-keeper
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
if [ ! -d "/var/log/hans-keeper" ]
then
        mkdir /var/log/hans-keeper
fi
target_file="$log_folder/$now"
exec_log(){
        echo "executing $1 and log into: $target_file"
        result=$(sudo $1)
        echo "$1" >> $target_file
        echo "-------------------------------------------------" >> $target_file
        printf "%s\n" $result >> $target_file
        echo "-------------------------------------------------" >> $target_file
        echo "" >> $target_file
}

exec_log /usr/bin/hans-keeper
exec_log /usr/bin/move-sync-staging
```

The `/usr/bin/hans-keeper` has a multi line echo like this:

```
echo "line 1"
echo "line 2"
echo "line 3"
```

As well as the `move-sync-staging`.

I see that executing `/usr/bin/hans-keeper` directly in the shell will print:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

But when i open the logfile from the result of the `/usr/bin/daily-execution`, it just print:

```
line 1line 2line 3
```

It appears that when executing the `/usr/bin/hans-keeper` script directly in the shell, the output does not include any newline characters.

I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue and improving my script.

Comment: Show the whole code and the exact commands you run to create the file and see the output. All of the code, including the part that prints line 1..line 3

Comment: It's probably the unquoted variable expansion in `printf "%s\n" $result` - see for example [echo variable with content from command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225963/echo-variable-with-content-from-command-substitution)

Comment: My tests on a simplified version agree with steeldriver that the issue comes from not putting double quotes around `$result` on the printf line.

Comment: What is the point of capturing `sudo something` to a variable only to print the variable? How about `sudo something >> "$target_file"`?

Comment: updated the details. @KamilMaciorowski ok ill try that one, i'm new in bash

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski apparently yours solve my issue, want to put that into answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```bash
>        echo "executing $1 and log into: $target_file"
>        result=$(sudo $1)
>        echo "$1" >> $target_file
>        echo "-------------------------------------------------" >> $target_file
>        printf "%s\n" $result >> $target_file
>        echo "-------------------------------------------------" >> $target_file
>        echo "" >> $target_file
> ```

Unquoted expansion of `$result` is the cause. Use `{ cmd1; cmd2 } >> file` instead of individual redirects.

```bash
exec_log() {
    echo "executing $1 and log into: $target_file"
    {
        echo "$1"
        echo "-------------------------------------------------"
        sudo "$1"
        echo "-------------------------------------------------"
        echo "" 
    }>> "$target_file"
}
```